# one Click event for multiple buttons with Text property

Tags: c#, events, button, text, properties

I want to make a click event for a bunch of buttons. The problem is that I want to use the button's Text, and pass it to a function. Now the click event is passed a object sender. When I tried changing that to Button sender, it gave errors. But I don't know how else I can work with the senders Text.

Here is the normal code, which gave a single error:

```
private void guess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     guess(sender.Text);
}
```

I changed it to this, which gave errors:

```
private void guess_Click(Button sender, EventArgs e)
{
     guess(sender.Text);
}
```

Question:
How can I work with the Button's Text property within this click event, which is a single click_event for multiple buttons?

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1:** You need to subscribe to the Button `Click` event of all your buttons to the same `EventHandler`. so that button click on all your Buttons will fire the same `Event Handler.

**Step 2:** You need to cast the object `sender` into `Button` and then access its `Text` property to get the Button Text.

Try This:

```
button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(MyButtonClick);
button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(MyButtonClick);
button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(MyButtonClick);

private void MyButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Button btnClick =  (Button)sender ;
  guess(btnClick.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast sender to type button.

Example:

```
private void guess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     guess(((Button)sender).Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the sender object to the `Button` type and use that:

```
private void guess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button senderBtn = senderBtn as Button;
    if(senderBtn != null)
    {
        guess(senderBtn.Text);
    }
}
```